# How to Django‘s InlineModelAdmin TabularInline or StackedInline show Thumbnail

Tags: django, django-admin, thumbnails

admin

```
class PersonInlines(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Person
    extra = 0

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (PersonInlines,)
    fields = ('name', )

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)

class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def image_thumbnail(self, obj):
        if obj.photo:
            image = FileObject(obj.photo.name)
            if image.filetype == "Image":
                return '<img src="%s" />' % image.version_generate(ADMIN_THUMBNAIL).url
    else:
        return ""

    image_thumbnail.allow_tags = True
    image_thumbnail.short_description = "Thumbnail"

    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'photo')
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'photo',)

admin.site.register(Person, PersonAdmin)
```

---

models

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    filename = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    ym = time.strftime('%Y%m')
    return 'uploads/%s/%s.jpg' % (ym,filename)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    photo = models.ImageField(u"Image (Upload)",upload_to=upload_to)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company')

    def image(self):
        if self.photo:
            return FileObject(self.photo.name)
        return None


class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

error
'PersonAdmin.fields' refers to field 'image_thumbnail' that is missing from the form.

How to Django‘s InlineModelAdmin  TabularInline or TabularInline  show Thumbnail

like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz2Ep.jpg

Comment: did this code worked for you ? i am getting this error FileObject not defined Error .. and I could not figure out how to import it .. any help is eagerly awaited .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer to `image_thumbnail` and not to `photo`.

```
fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'image_thumbnail')
```

Though you might consider using this [mixin-approach](http://haineault.com/blog/174/).